# How to Include a Function in a Namespace Using Namespace Aliases

Tags: c++, namespaces, namespace-alias

The following header is a simplified version of the actual, overly convoluted code. I need to add a function, in an implementation file, to the same namespace as `f()`. How do I do this, considering that **I cannot directly use `V`**?.

Thank you.

```
// framework header file
namespace N
{
  namespace V {} // not to be used outside header; use the alias below, instead
  namespace VA = V; // using VA outside header is fine
  using namespace V;
  namespace V
  {
    void f();
  }
}

// client impl file
namespace N
{
  namespace V // not allowed
  {
    void g() // this must belong to N::V
    {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I _think_ this is not possible. But this is only a hunch.

Comment: @einpoklum I also think the same, but I'm still hoping.

Comment: Have an upvote for keeping the faith then :-)